# Data retrieving issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I'm trying display some data in my blade. Following is my current code for the controller's(ActivateController.php) index function,

```
 public function index($id)
    {
        //echo $id;
        $datas = Website::WHERE('appId','=',$id);
        //dd($datas);
        return view('activities.index',compact('datas','id'));         
    }
```

And my view url is something like,

```
TEST.site/activities/index/12
```

this is my blade, index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')


@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h2 class="mt-2">Activate Website</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('websites.index') }}"> Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="container ">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
  <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
    <ul>
       @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
         <li>{{ $error }}</li>
       @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endif

<div class="container mt-3">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">


@foreach ($datas as $object)

<form id="w1" action="{{ route('activities.update',$object->appId) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                        <strong>Select Package Type:<span class="star">*</span></strong>
                        <input type="text" name="app_domain" value="{{$object->domain}}">
                            <strong>Select Package Type:<span class="star">*</span></strong>
                            <select id="app-packagetype" class="form-control" name="package_type" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="{{$object->payment_option }}">{{$object->payment_option }}</option>
                                <option value="monthly">Monthly [12]</option>
                                <option value="yearly">Yearly [99]</option>
                            </select>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group text-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{ __('Activate') }}</button>
                        </div>

</form>
 @endforeach

</div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

But now my issue is , when I try to retrieve the data,

```
{{$object->appId}}
```

It retrieves empty....

Where I'm doing wrong and how to retrieve the data properly to the view?

Comment: You never `->get()` your results, so `$datas` is a query builder object, not your website collection.

Comment: Don't use `::WHERE()`. Your local environment may not be case sensitive, but if this code goes to one that is, your code will not work. `::where()` is the correct casing for that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `get()` at the end

change this:

```
$datas = Website::where('appId','=',$id);
```

to

```
$datas = Website::where('appId','=',$id)->get();
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You use just like this

```
$datas = Website::where('appId',$id)->get();
```